# Can I stop a cell's disclosure indicator from turning white when selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a cell where the accessory type is set to a disclosure indicator via:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Now when selected, it turns white as per default.

Because I have changed the default selection style/view via the cell's 'backgroundView' and 'selectedBackgroundView' properties, I want the disclosure indicator to stay gray as it will look better.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to create a custom disclosure indicator image and adding this to the cell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this link:[Custom colored disclosure indicators](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I prefer this method to using images. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `-setHighlighted:animated:` and `-setSelected:animated`. In these methods, you set the `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`. From here all you need to do is add a gray disclosure indicator to your `selectedBackgroundView`.

Comment: That means I still need to create a disclosure indicator myself. The question is asking if there is an easy way to do it without having to create an image or anything :)